# How can I capture the file dialog closing event in angular after user selected some files or cancel it ? thank you

Tags: angular, input, onclick, openfiledialog

How can I capture the event of file dialog closing after user selected some file in angular?

I have tried with (change) when user changes values for the input

I need to capture the event once the user selected some file and file dialog closes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's possible.
What do you want to do exactly ?